# Generating a large list of strings to the console

Tags: java, string, console

I'm trying to generate a list (upwards of 500000) of random hexadecimal values. I need a count of how many unique values there are and be able to copy and paste the hexadecimals into a text file. However, when I try to copy the values from the console, I lose strings. For example, 40000 hexadecimal values were created but the console only has about 6000 values listed. The program works for smaller numbers and always tells me the correct amount of unique values.

```
   public class HexGenerator {
     private static String getRandomHexString(int numchars) {
       Random r = new Random();
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
       while (sb.length() < numchars) {
         sb.append(Integer.toHexString(r.nextInt()));
       }

       return sb.toString().substring(0, numchars);
     }
     public static void main(String args[]) {
       LinkedList < String > address = new LinkedList < String > ();
       for (int x = 0; x < 40000; x++) {
         String a = getRandomHexString(4);
         System.out.println("7f1a9800" + a + " ");


         if (!address.contains(a))
           address.add(a);
       }
       System.out.println();
       System.out.println(address.size());
     }
   }
```

How can I get all the strings to print in the console?

Comment: Don't print them to the console: redirect the output of your program into a file `command > output.txt`.

Comment: By the way, LinkedList is a poor choice of collection to check for duplicates. The contains operation is O(n). If you don't require the contents in any particular order (e.g. you just want to check contains), use a HashSet, which implements contains as an O(1) operation (and use a LinkedHashSet if you want the insertion order to be preserved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your console has it's own limits. To redirect all of the output to the text file use "java MyProgram > somefile.txt" (works for both Linux and Windows I believe).

Comment: Do I have to write all output to a text file using the terminal or can I use eclipse? Second, does the file being written to already have to exist?

Comment: If you use `>`, the file will be created if it doesn't exist and overwritten if it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse then go to Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console and deselect Limit console output.